# framework not found .xcframework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5, xcframework

I have created a **.xcframework** using Xcode 11.0 command line. And it is working fine if I simply drag and drop it on any Xcode project above Xcode 11.0. I have tried on Xcode 11.0, 11.1, 11.2.1 and it is working perfectly on them. Now I am trying to use it through Cocoapods. To do so I have created podspec file given the local path of the framework. It is installing the pods successfully as well into the project. But now when I am trying to build the project it is getting failed by saying

**ld: framework not found RandomNames.xcframework**

I am not sure where the problem is, because it is working fine if we use directly dragging into the project.
I have checked the framework search path, tried to pod disintegrate, clean and install them again but no success.

This is what error I am getting:

[image]

and below is my .podspec file which I am using:

[image]

Comment: Judging from [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9148) I guess support for xcframeworks is not (yet) implemented.

Comment: Yes, i also think so. Please updated me here if you found any news related to the support for this. Thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they've added [support](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/9334) for xcframeworks now and released a [beta](https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.9.0-beta/) version (CocoaPods 1.9 Beta).
Try giving it a shot! :)